# Как установить pandas в termux?

Tags: python, pandas, termux

Я пытаюсь установить pandas в termux разными способами, но всё время сталкиваюсь с ошибками.
Мне удалось установить numpy(Что тоже было довольно проблематично но как я понял он нужен для установки pandas), но это не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Но как мне с телефона вставить код ошибки иначе?

Comment: termux позволяет выделить и скопировать текст, если вы вдруг почему-то не в курсе

Comment: А сама ошибка намекает на то, что нужно установить компилятор для компиляции pandas (правда, компиляция на телефоне будет долгой и мучительной)

Comment: Ну а вообще https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/10oal39/pandas_install_fails_building_wheel_for_old_numpy/

Comment: это не помогло, но похоже я понял в чём причина